# I need help forming a specific regular expression(Example Inside)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to build a regular expression that finds a string of this format:

```
[name] => X\n
```

Where X is equal to the name of something and `\n` is a line break.  I would like to somehow return `X` in an array using `preg_match`.

Comment: Are you parsing print_r output?

Comment: Yes I am parsing print_r output, and \n is a line break.

Comment: If you have control over your input - instead of print_r you may use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` functions

Comment: I don't have control over the input.  I am parsing through logs that at one point used this method.

Comment: If you are on linux - you may be better off using some bash commands like grep, sort, uniq etc. They're faster than PHP

Comment: It turned out that I had most of it right all along, I just included a ^ at the beginning of the regex, and there are tabs in print_r output, so it didn't match anything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\[.*\] => (.*)$`

http://rubular.com/

Comment: This is an awesome method, but I have to do this operation thousands of times.  Is there anyway I can specifically target the [name] section of the output?

Comment: put the particular name inside the `\\[NameOfInterest\\]`